# How to stop event faking (toggle event faking) in Laravel unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-events

I am developing a Laravel application and doing the unit test. Now, I am having a bit of an issue with faking and un-faking Laravel event in the unit test. What I am trying to do is something like this.

```
public function test_something()
{
     Event::fake();
     //Do somethng
     //Then I want to stop faking event here something like this
     Event::stopFaking(); //maybe
}
```

I think my code is self-explanatory. How can I achieve something like that in Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking

> If you only want to fake event listeners for a portion of your test, you may use the fakeFor method:

```
    $order = Event::fakeFor(function () {
        $order = factory(Order::class)->create();

        Event::assertDispatched(OrderCreated::class);

        return $order;
    });

    // Events are dispatched as normal and observers will run ...
    $order->update([...]);
```

Everything inside the `function() {}` will have faked events. Everything outside will function normally.

Comment: Thanks mate. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `Event::fake` function is defined in [Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8ccb11d7bf376248f2a362f0e11e874965b3ad3b/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Event.php).

We can see that there is a `fakeFor` method that only fakes it during the execution of a callback method, then restores the original behavior. You can use it like this:

```
public function test_something()
{
     Event::fakeFor(function () {
         //Do somethng
     });
}
```

As a Laravel developer it is often useful to read the source code, there are lots of nice bits and pieces in this framework that are not documented!

Comment: I'd just like to note that this behavior *is* documented.